# must we specify the cardinlaty anotation in the entity?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entity, java-ee-6

I'm a new `JAVA-EE` Developper & I wonder if we are obliged to specify the cardinality annotations(`@OneToOne`,`@ManyToOne`...) in an `Entity Class`, even if we use the `@JoinColumn` annotation ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try not to use them?

Comment: @AmerQarabsa actionely not, but i'm not talking about the syntaxic side, but about the `java-ee Standards`

Comment: You need to specify the type of the mapping, but you could know this by attempting

Comment: `@OneToOne` in conjunction with `@JoinColumn` will result in the generation of the join column **along with a unique constraint for that column** (to *actually* enforce a one-to-one association). This will not be the case for `@ManyToOne`. As you can see, the `@JoinColumn` alone is inconclusive as far as schema generation goes

Comment: @crizzis thank you

Answer (score 0):

When using just the @JoinColumn annotation, The framework can not guess the type of relationship you want to have (is it a OneToOne or OneToMany ... ?), even if it recognizes the associated entities.

On the other hand, it is not obligatory to mention the @JoinColumn because it's optional.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html

Comment: I though the it was the opposite, I mean that the cardinality is optional & the `@JoinColum` is necessary. Thanks for your answer

Comment: The cardinality was never optional ; the `@JoinColumn` is used instead of `@Column` wich is used with **primitive attributes**.